# Parse JSON to Angular object?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a JSON similar to the following:

```
{
  "A01": "DescA",
  "A02": "DescB",
  "A03": "DescC",
  "A04": "DescE"
}
```

And a class defined like this:

```
export class Element {
    public id: string;
    public description: string;
}
```

How can I parse the JSON and get an `Element` array with `el[0].id == "A01"` and `el[0].description == "DescA"` and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export class Element {
  public id: string;
  public description: string;
}

const data = {
  "A01": "DescA",
  "A02": "DescB",
  "A03": "DescC",
  "A04": "DescE"
};


const elements: Element[] = Object.keys(data)
  .map(key => {
    const element = new Element();
    element.description = data[key];
    element.id = key;
    return element;
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your JSON has a "customized" sturcture (which means it is not the same result as serializing an `Element` object), you need to assign values manually

```js
class Element {
    id = "";
    description = "";
    
    
    constructor(id, desc){
       this.id = id;
       this.description = desc;
    }
};

const apiResult = {
  "A01": "DescA",
  "A02": "DescB",
  "A03": "DescC",
  "A04": "DescE"
};



const elementArray = Object.keys(apiResult).map(key => new Element(key, apiResult[key]));

console.log(elementArray);
```

Or (I assume you are using Angular 2+) you can use [`typestack/class-transformer`](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) library to parse/deserialize from JSON by using decorators. It has some advantage such as nested deserialization.